# how to resolve Runtime Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined?

Tags: runtime-error

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/Storage';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

import { RegisterPage } from '../pages/register/register';

@Component({ 
    templateUrl: 'app.html' 
}) 
export class MyApp {

  _platform: Platform;

  public get platform(): Platform {
    return this._platform;
  }

  public set platform(value: Platform) {
    this._platform = value;
  }

  @ViewChild('content') nav: NavController; rootPage: any;
  initialization: any; initializationApp: any; Platform: any;
  statusBar: any; splashScreen: any; Storage: any;

  constructor(public platform1: Platform, public StatusBar:
    StatusBar, public SplashScreen: SplashScreen, private storage:
      Storage) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });

    this.storage.get('session_storage').then((res) => {
      if (res == null) {
        this.rootPage = LoginPage;
      } else {
        this.rootPage = HomePage;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your references to injected stuff inside constructor are the same as you call them in your methods. For example you have also name capital letters etc...

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/Storage';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

import { RegisterPage } from '../pages/register/register';

@Component({ 
    templateUrl: 'app.html' 
}) 
export class MyApp {

  @ViewChild('content') nav: NavController; 
  rootPage: any;
  initialization: any; 
  initializationApp: any;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar:
    StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, private storage:
      Storage) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });

    this.storage.get('session_storage').then((res) => {
      if (res == null) {
        this.rootPage = LoginPage;
      } else {
        this.rootPage = HomePage;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

you call platform while in your constructor you initialized platform1.
To fix update your constructor to point at "platform"

Comment: I did this, I now get the following error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'styleDefault' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'styleDefault' of undefined

Comment: sorry for english, I'm brazilian

Comment: @ens0mx hey dude this is because the injected names in your constructor are different from what you call in method. Please ensure what is in your constructor is exactly what is called in your methods. I am updating the method now

Comment: also let me know why you have the setter/getter for platform?

Comment: the setter and the getter I put to stop receiving the error: duplicate identifier platform

Comment: weird, you only need to import platform once, inject in constructor and that is it. Why would you get it duplicated? sorry still do not understand your use case

Comment: see I updated your code cleaned out all the unnecessary stuff.Try plz

Comment: I just received this error:    Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyApp: (?, [object Object], [object Object], ?).  and thank you for helping me